# Summarize X by Y using top N sorted by Z

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Kusto allows me to create summarize statistics sliced on some column based on the top on rows of a table ordered by some rule. For example, if I want to compute the average Score of each Location using the last 100 rows, I can write

```
T | top 100 by Time | summarize avg(Score) by Location
```

But I want the top to apply to each bin of the summarize. For example, I want to compute the average of the last 10 Scores available for each Location. I don't see how I can do this. At first I thought I might be able to use top-nested by it only returns the top n Locations; I want to return records for all Locations, and use the top n of each to compute an aggregate. I am willing to do this via something that effectively repeats a query for each Location, but I need the final result to be in one table with columns Location and AvgOfLast10Scores.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Please edit your question to include a short sample input (in datatable format), and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `partition by` then `summarize`:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Location:string, Score: int) 
[
    "01/01/2021", "Texas", 1,
    "01/02/2021", "Texas", 2,
    "01/03/2021", "Texas", 4,
    "01/03/2021", "Alabama", 1,
    "01/04/2021", "Alabama", 3,
    "01/05/2021", "Alabama", 4,
];
T
| partition by Location (top 2 by Timestamp)
| summarize avg(Score) by Location
```

Results:

[image: query results]

You might also be able to use `top-nested`, but I find top-nested confusing. You can read more about partition in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator)

Comment: This is simpler than the other solution but currently works only if the number of distinct locations is 64 or less.

Comment: Thanks for this, and thanks to @Avnera for calling out the 64 row limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option (in this example it will take the last two measurements):

```
datatable(Time:datetime, Location: string, Score:int)[datetime(2021-01-10), "a", 6, 
    datetime(2021-01-10 01:00), "a", 7,
    datetime(2021-01-10 02:00), "a", 8,
    datetime(2021-01-10 03:00), "a", 10,
    datetime(2021-01-10), "b", 10,
    datetime(2021-01-10 01:00), "b", 20,
    datetime(2021-01-10 02:00), "b", 30,
    datetime(2021-01-10 03:00), "b", 40]
| order by Location asc, Time desc 
| extend rowNumber = row_number(0, Location != prev(Location))
| where rowNumber <= 1
| summarize avg(Score) by Location
```

And the results:
[image]